# kafka-console-consumer with kerberos throws No enum constant exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos

I have enabled Kerberos for Kafka from Ambari. For me, console producer is working with below command

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test --producer-property security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

While consume data using below command I am getting below error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol.

Console consumer command what I have used is

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test --consumer-property security.protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Comment: It is because of missing '=' symbol in console consumer command. Should be security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

Comment: Yes it is working now